# i've been trying to get this code to work for hours and I've tried to fix it in multiple ways and it still doesn't work

Tags: python, oop

i've been trying to get this to work for hours and I've tried to fix it in multiple ways and it still doesn't work.

```
# this creates my class "bucket"
class bucket:
    def __init__(self, water, capcity):
        self.water = water
        self.capcity = capcity


# here I create my objects
bucket1 = bucket(0, 3)
bucket2 = bucket(0, 5)


# this is the printing code to print how much water there is in every bucket
def pr_v():
    print("Bucket_ONE " + str(bucket1.water) + "L")
    print("Bucket_TWO " + str(bucket2.water) + "L")
    print(" ")


# this is where my problem is
# this scirpt is supposed to trasfer water from the pouring bucket (p_bucket) to the receiving bucket untill the receiving bucket reaches it's
# capacity or the pouring bucket runs out of water
def pour_water(p_bucket, g_bucket):
    while g_bucket.capcity >= g_bucket.water or p_bucket.water != -1:
        if g_bucket.capcity != g_bucket.water or p_bucket.water != -1:

            if g_bucket.capcity < g_bucket.water:
                bucket.water = g_bucket.capcity
                break
            p_bucket.water -= 1
            g_bucket.water += 1
            pr_v()

    if p_bucket.water == -1:
        p_bucket.water = 0


# this fills the bucket to it's capacity 
def fill_water(self):
    self.water = self.capcity


fill_water(bucket2)
pour_water(bucket2, bucket1)
pr_v()
```

when I execute the code this happens

```
Bucket_ONE 1L
Bucket_TWO 4L
 
Bucket_ONE 2L
Bucket_TWO 3L
```

it's supposed to stop here because bucket 1 reaches its capacity

↓

```
Bucket_ONE 3L
Bucket_TWO 2L
 
Bucket_ONE 4L
Bucket_TWO 1L
 
Bucket_ONE 4L
Bucket_TWO 1L
```

why does this happen?
Im new to coding so I might not know a lot of stuff

Thanks

Comment: Does the down arrow mean that you do not expect the output below, but you get it?

Comment: You should read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

Boy did you over complicate this...

```
def pour_water(p_bucket, g_bucket):
    while not p_bucket.is_full() and not g_bucket.is_empty():
        p_bucket += 1
        g_bucket -= 1
        pr_v()
```

I am going to leave the implementation of "is_full" and "is_empty" to you.
Good luck

Comment: thank you so much! this way is much easier, but do you know why it didn't work in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the following line to add the equals sign:

```
 if g_bucket.capcity <= g_bucket.water:
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the last `pr_v()` it just prints the result again after printing it in your method or remove the `pr_v()` from your method so that you only see the result